Trino writing data to S3
When i try to run a query on S3 to create table from another table like
CREATE TABLE s3.newmodifiedtable WITH ( format='csv',location='s3a://bucket/key') AS (select * from old table where <filter>)

Now this query will write data into new location of S3. Who is responsible for writing. coordinator or worker and whats their(worker and coordinator) role in whole process?
